# Cross thread invoke exception

Tags: c#, winforms

In order to change a control by another thread, I need to invoke a delegate to change the control However, it is throwing a `TargetParameterCountException`:

```
private void MethodParamIsObjectArray(object[] o) {}
private void MethodParamIsIntArray(int[] o) {}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        // This will throw a System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException exception
        Invoke(new Action<object[]>(MethodParamIsObjectArray), new object[] { });
        // It works
        Invoke(new Action<int[]>(MethodParamIsIntArray), new int[] { });
}
```

Why does invoking with `MethodParamIsObjectArray` throw an exception?

Comment: Not sure why the need for `Invoke` inside `button1_Click` considering the _current thread will already be the UI thread_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the `Invoke` method has a signature of:

```
object Invoke(Delegate method, params object[] args)
```

The `params` keyword in front of the `args` parameter indicates that this method can take a variable number of objects as parameters. When you supply an array of objects, it is functionally equivalent to passing multiple comma-separated objects. The following two lines are functionally equivalent:

```
Invoke(new Action<object[]>(MethodParamIsObjectArray), new object[] { 3, "test" });
Invoke(new Action<object[]>(MethodParamIsObjectArray), 3, "test");
```

The proper way to pass an object array into `Invoke` would be to cast the array to type `Object`:

```
Invoke(new Action<object[]>(MethodParamIsObjectArray), (object)new object[] { 3, "test" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke expects an array of objects containing the parameter values.

In the first call, you aren't providing any values. You need one value, which confusingly needs to be an object array itself.

```
new object[] { new object[] { }  }
```

In the second case, you need an array of objects containing an array of integers.

```
new object[] { new int[] { }  }
```